# Click element without recording JMETER

Tags: jmeter

I wanna know How can I click element without recording on jmeter? Can I use BeanShell for this or something else? Just I want to click something on web page.
Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If "click" generates a [HTTP request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods) - JMeter will record it, if it doesn't generate a HTTP request, for example does something solely on client side (change sorting order in a table, increase font, etc.) - JMeter will not record it.

If you don't want to record a certain event you can just [disable proxy in your browser](https://www.wikihow.com/Disable-Proxy-Settings), this way even if there is a HTTP Request associated with the click - it will not be recorded by the [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder).

There is also possibility to [exclude certain requests from recording](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732519-Excluding-Domains-from-the-Load-Test-Excluding-Domains-from-the-Load-Test) by providing a regular expression pattern, this way you won't need to amend proxy configuration, JMeter will automatically exclude certain patterns and will not create [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers for matching URLs

Comment: Click does not generate any http request. This reason I am tring to click manually. I have to click there but Jmeter does not take it. Do you have any idea about that?

Comment: If it doesn't generate any request you don't need to click it as the action happens on the client side

Comment: but page changes in partly,just a part of page is changing. I dont know how :)// some input areas is hidden in page and when I click button this hidden part comes appear. I am trying WebSampler. Ithink it will work.

Comment: If no network request is there then the part of UI is [hidden via CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp), however it still present in the response so you should be able to perform [correlations](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start), [assertions](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps/), etc. You can use [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/) but be aware that it has huge footprint (1 CPU core and 2 GB of RAM per browser instance)

Comment: the case is that : ı wanna login one site. this site has 2 option to login. first one needs 2 input to login. Second one needs 3 input. I have to login with first option. Both options have same url, all of the page behind is same. Because of that my thought is if I click firts option I can login with 2 input but also WebDriver Sampler didnot work for now. I am working on it.

Comment: Just record the login process using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) or [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-new-blazeMeter-chrome-extension-v4-easily-script-jmeter-and-selenium/), you don't need to "click" anything in order to send the request

Comment: I am trying to say recording does not catch the option change. It catch default one which second option.And I dont want that

Comment: Record both scenarios and compare resulting HTTP Request samplers, you should be able to see the difference

Comment: I recorded but post request almost same. When I record with 2 input option Jmeter catch third input and live it empty.